# Ubuntu 20.04 Ubuntu Software Without background

Tags: software-center

[image]I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and the app "Ubuntu Software" is loading transparent without a proper background, please tell if there's a fix for this, or if anyone else is facing the same issue.
The screenshot is attached in the file.
Thanks.